# Translating rpm commands to dpkg

Tags: rpm, dpkg

I've been using RPM for a long time - built my own packages and installed Linux with nothing but the RPMs to do it with.

However, now that I'm using Ubuntu and Linux Mint regularly, I want to learn more about dpkg but don't know where to start.

Particularly, I find myself missing commands like:

- rpm --queryformat="..."  (query database for data and print in user-defined format)
- rpm --whatrequires  (find out what requires a package)
- rpm -qV  (verify all files on the filesystem)

And there are more.  Where can I find the best translator?

**UPDATE:** I've located two that I didn't know about when I wrote this question. One is [APT and RPM Packager Lookup Tables](http://www.jpsdomain.org/linux/apt.html) from J. P. Vossen. The other is from Ubuntu and is called [Switching To Ubuntu From Linux Red Hat Enterprise Linux And Fedora](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora). Both pages are quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a good 'translator'.  You could write one up, though!  Note that in the debian world (where dpkg comes from), you'll need not just dpkg but also possibly other tools like dpkg-* apt-cache to show you some of those things.

rpm --queryformat is approximately the same as dpkg-query.

rpm --whatrequires is approximately the same as apt-cache rdepends.

rpm -qV is approximately the same as the debsums

That should get you started :)

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like that dpkg has more "commands" than RPM does: separate commands where RPM has just one (or two, if you count rpmbuild).

Answer (score -2):

Like pjz said, I don't think there's a good translator of sorts. Is it that you only have a rpm of a file and can't find a .deb version? dpkg handles .deb files much like rpm handles .rpm files. Have you tried looking in the apt-get listing? A handy trick I've found is typing in the first part of a package name and hitting tab; it either completes my list or gives me matching packages.

Comment: That doesn't help.  Firstly, I'm familiar with apt-get - I've used APT-RPM for years and resoundingly encourage using it.  I think apt is fantastic (can't say the same for dpkg...).  Secondly, I don't use bash, but ksh: so I strongly suspect completion would not work there.